# How does a RF-induced evaporative cooling remove hotter atoms in the dressed state picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, cold-atoms

I am stuck in the problem of evaporative cooling in a magnetic trap.

$\textbf{Introduction}$

In the magnetic trap, I assumed the trap is an Ioffe-Pritchard trap. So the Majorona loss is prohibited. The potential of atoms in the trap is:

$$
V=-\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}=g_F\frac{\mu_B}{\hbar}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{B}(\vec{r})
$$

$$
\vec{B}(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0}{\pi d^2}(x\hat{x}-y\hat{y})+\hat{z}\Big(B(z=0)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2B}{dz^2}z^2\Big)
$$
$d$ is the separation of adjacent pair of Ioffe coils. $z$-component is from the pinch coil.

Suppose the magnetic field is way smaller than the coupling between nucleus and electronic angular momentum. So $|F,m_F\rangle$ basis vectors are available. In this basis, the potential looks like: $V=g_Fm_F\mu_B B(\vec{r}).$ Now each local magnetic field provides a quantization axis. The adiabatic requirement is: $\omega_{Lamor}\gg\omega_{trap}.$ So when atoms move in the trap, they always precess around the same quantization axis.

The trappable state requires $g_Fm_F>0.$ Now I assume the system is a two level system. One state is trappable state and another one is untrappable state. For cooling atoms, the rf-induced field is an option. When I put rf field in the trap, the external coupling also looks like $\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}_{rf}$ (Of course, the polarization axis of rf field must be normal to the local magnetic field so that the spin flip is possible.)

The induced rf field is like a cap to limit those trappable atoms.

[image]

At the intersection of blue dashed line and the quadratic potential, spin of atoms should be flipped then they become to an untrappable state and go away.

$\textbf{Hamiltonian}: $Rf-field is quantized

Now I design/approximate my system as:(rotating wave approximation is considered)

$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\omega_0(\vec{r})\sigma_z+\hbar\omega_{rf} a^{\dagger}a+\hbar\lambda(\sigma^+a+\sigma^-a^{\dagger})
$$
and express them in the basis of \$|t,n\rangle, |u,n+1\rangle\$ and find out the eigenstate of H. Those two dressed states are:

$$
\begin{cases}
|+\rangle &=\cos{\frac{\theta_n}{2}} |t,n\rangle+\sin{\frac{\theta_n}{2}}|u,n+1\rangle\\
|-\rangle &=-\sin{\frac{\theta_n}{2}}|t,n\rangle+\cos{\frac{\theta_n}{2}}|u,n+1\rangle
\end{cases}
$$

$\cos{\frac{\theta_n}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_n(\Delta)+\Delta}{2\Omega_n(\Delta)}},\ \sin{\frac{\theta_n}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_n(\Delta)-\Delta}{2\Omega_n(\Delta)}},\ \Delta=\omega_{rf}-\omega_0(\vec{r}) $

[image]

$\textbf{Dressed state picture} $

Now I assume trapped atoms start moving from the trapped atom cloud toward the evaporation shell. At the beginning the detuning is large. As atoms move toward the evaporation shell the detuning turns small. For slow moving atoms, they need to spend very long time to reach the location of resonance. So the trappable slow moving atoms walks on the adiabatic path and finally become untrappable.

However, for fast moving atoms, the quantum tunneling would occur(according to Landau-Zener formula) when they pass through the evaporation shell($\Delta=0$). So after passing through the evaporation shell they are in the $|-\rangle$ so finally the spin flip does $\textbf{NOT} $ work on those fast moving atoms and they are still in the trappable state but for those slow moving atoms, spin flip works. If so, why does the evaporative cooling still work?